# What does a circular number icon on an item mean?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

Some items in my backpack have a circular number icon near their description. These number icons aren't listed in the search filters and don't appear if I check the same items in storage or a shop. What do these circular number icons mean?

[image: Pickax with a 7 icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circular number icon indicates which slot the item is equipped to on your Item Ring.

(Item slots have been numbered in the screenshot below for demonstration)

[image: Item Ring with slots labeled 1 to 8]